# How to get the parent LI index and the sub LI index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyrx459k/

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $('.ul1 li').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var liIndex = $(this).index('li');
        console.log(liIndex);
    );
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="ul1" id="ul1">
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test3</a>
        <ul class="ul2">
            <li><a href="">Test3 - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Test3 - 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test4</a>
        <ul class="ul2">
            <li><a href="">Test4 - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Test4 - 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I modify the script to have the following:

- When a parent LI (`Test#`) is clicked the console will display the index - for example, clicking on `Test4` will output a `3` (fourth item)
- When clicking on a sub LI (`Test# - #`) it will display the parent index and the child index - for example, clicking on `Test3 - 1` will output `2.0` (2 being the parent LI and 0 being the first child sub LI)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ul1 li').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var i = $(this).parentsUntil('#ul1').add(this).map(function () {
            return this.tagName === 'LI' ? $(this).index() : null;
        }).get().join('.');
    });
});
```

Comment: Very sweet solution but `$(this).parentsUntil('#ul1').add(this)` would be enough, right?

Comment: I dropped this code in SiK's fiddle and it doesn't do anything. What else is needed to make the fiddle show something in console?

Comment: @A.Wolff embarrassing. Just add the console.log - my bad. However, Firefox isn't logging anything but Chrome is. Firefox bug or JSFiddle bug?

Comment: @A.Wolff and even nicer is it if you chose `jQuery(edge)` at the left and enalbe `Firebug` http://jsfiddle.net/fyrx459k/2/

Comment: Here is sweeter one imho: http://jsfiddle.net/z44pxvgo/3/   `$(this).parents('li').add(this).map(function () {
            return $(this).index();
        })`

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks. Yes, that's true. At first I decided to use a different solution using the `closest` method, then I decided to use the `parentsUntil` method. That's why `this.parentNode` was there. And yes, using `parentsUntil`  method's `filter` parameter is a very good suggestion.

Comment: @ThisClark That should be `firebug` bug! Sometimes it doesn't log anything.

Comment: @SiKni8 NO, it is not.

Answer (score 5):

A pretty basic solution using `$(this).parents("li")`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.ul1 li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var liIndex = "";
    var $parents = $(this).parents("li");
    if ($parents.length > 0)
      liIndex += ($parents.index() + 1) + ".";
    liIndex += ($(this).index() + 1);
    alert(liIndex);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul1" id="ul1">
  <li><a href="">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Test3</a>
    <ul class="ul2">
      <li><a href="">Test3 - 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Test3 - 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Test4</a>
    <ul class="ul2">
      <li><a href="">Test4 - 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Test4 - 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is very easy to understand solution

Answer (score 2):

I love html5 tags, so check if this solution can be useful. Otherwise you can do the same thing with the ID or whatever you prefer.

```js
function checkIndex(element) {
  deepCheck(element, '');
}
     
function deepCheck(element, index) {
  if($(element).data('index') && $(element).is('li')) {
    var newIndex = '';
    if(index.length === 0) {
      newIndex = 'Element indexes: ' + $(element).data('index')
    } else {
      newIndex = index + ' - ' + $(element).data('index');
    }
    deepCheck($(element).parent(), newIndex);
  } else if($(element).data('root')) {
    alert(index);
  } else {
    deepCheck($(element).parent(), index)
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkIndex(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-root="true" class="ul1" id="ul1">
    <li data-index="1"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li data-index="2"><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
    <li data-index="3"><a href="#">Test3</a>
        <ul class="ul2">
            <li data-index="1"><a href="#">Test3 - 1</a></li>
            <li data-index="2"><a href="#">Test3 - 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-index="4"><a href="#">Test4</a>
        <ul class="ul2">
            <li data-index="1"><a href="#">Test4 - 1</a></li>
            <li data-index="2"><a href="#">Test4 - 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works well also, although it is a lot of code. Thank you regardless. +1 for the solution

Answer (score 2):

Use `parents('li')` to check if the clicked `li` has a `li` ancestor, `.index()` to determine the index of a `li`, `.preventDefault()` to stop the click from following the link and `.stopPropagation` to stop event from bubbling. This should do it:

```
$('#ul1 li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var arr = [];
    arr.push( $(this).index() );
    !$(this).parents('li').length ||
    arr.push( $(this).parents('li').index() );
    console.log( arr.reverse().join('.') );
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#ul1 li').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var arr = [];
        arr.push( $(this).index() );
        !$(this).parents('li').length ||
        arr.push( $(this).parents('li').index() );
        console.log( arr.reverse().join('.') );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul1" id="ul1">
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test3</a>
        <ul class="ul2">
            <li><a href="">Test3 - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Test3 - 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test4</a>
        <ul class="ul2">
            <li><a href="">Test4 - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Test4 - 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest returning false. It removes the need to use both preventDefault and stopPropagation, and also to store the event in e.

Further, some more structured selections would be helpful here. There are only two cases to handle, where a parent element classed ul2 exits and where not. In the case it does, there needs to be two queries to determine the parents index and the current index with regards to the ul2 element. In the case where it does not, then only the relative ul1 index needs to be determined.

I included some extra elements to show the need for a more targeted approach.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.ul1 li').click(function() {
        var ul2 = $(this).closest('.ul2'),
        location = ul2.length > 0 ? 
            ul2.parent().index('.ul1 > li')+"."+ul2.find('li').index(this) :
            $(this).index('.ul1 > li');
        log(location);
        return false;
    });
});
function log(msg){ $("#result").text(msg); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul1" id="ul1">
 <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Test2</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Test3</a>
  <ul class="ul2">
   <li><a href="">Test3 - 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Test3 - 2</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="">Test4</a>
  <ul class="ul2">
   <li><a href="">Test4 - 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Test4 - 2</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
<div id="result"></div>
```